# local Wordpress site breaks when enabling CMSMasters Elementor Addon with Elementor

Tags: wordpress

I bought a theme from themeforest and imported the demo/dummy data, and afterward gave this blank page with a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in D:\xampp\htdocs\bankofoscartopia\wp-content\plugins\elementor\includes\template-library\sources\local.php:897 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\bankofoscartopia\wp-content\themes\stereo-bank\admin\installer\importer\elementor-templates.php(172): Elementor\TemplateLibrary\Source_Local->import_template('templates_path-...', 'D:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\bankofoscartopia\wp-content\themes\stereo-bank\admin\installer\importer\elementor-templates.php(107): StereoBankSpace\Admin\Installer\Importer\Elementor_Templates->import_templates('templates_path')
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\bankofoscartopia\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(324): StereoBankSpace\Admin\Installer\Importer\Elementor_Templates->admin_init_actions('')
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\bankofoscartopia\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #4 D:\xampp\htdocs\bankofoscartopia\wp-includes\plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #5 D:\xampp\htdocs\bankofoscartopia\wp-admin\admin.php(175): do_action('admin_init') #6 D:\xampp\htdocs\bankofoscartopia\wp-admin\index.php(10): require_once('D:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #7 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\bankofoscartopia\wp-content\plugins\elementor\includes\template-library\sources\local.php on line 897
```

For some reason if I remove the CMSMasters Elementor Addon it works, but the issue is there's no buttons and things are missing since it's required by the theme. What does any of this mean?

I removed each plugin it came with, and manually installed them one by one and activated them in order, even before importing the theme and it's the same issue.